# Should I bring up a suspended/restricted driver's license with a potential employer before a background check?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, background-check

I accumulated 4 speeding violations in the last year and this resulted in a temporarily restricted license - it shows up on my MVR as suspended.

I have to go through a background check through HireRight, which includes an MVR segment.

It's for a corporate analyst position with minimal travel. I've also been working at the company for the prior 2 months as a contractor - they liked my work so I was extended a full-time offer.

However, I'm worried it may be revoked once HR sees the MVR. Is it best to raise the matter to HR before they see the HireRight report? I never interviewed or filled out a formal application yet.

Comment: Your drivers license has nothing to do with your position as an analyst and you obviously do not need it for your job. It is very hard to believe that this will pose *insurmountable* obstacles to you being hired. BTW what exactly is an MVR?

Comment: You didn't say where you are located. But in California for instance, it's illegal to discriminate on a factor that is not directly related to the job description in question. For instance, it's illegal for an employer to even ask if you own a car, or have access to a car, or if your commute from home is going to be long, unless it's directly relevant to the job at hand. For instance, if the job requires you to deliver pizza with your own car, they can ask about the car, or if you're an on-call Emergency Room nurse that needs to live 20 minutes away from your hospital, they can ask about that.

Comment: In other words, if you wrote this down on your application, the HR at my old job would have been forced to black it out with a magic marker, because it's their job to make sure that the hiring manager doesn't see some things that they could discriminate on. In other words, disclosing this little fact only makes the job of HR harder, not easier. Don't do it. And even if you're not located in California, I would still recommend that you don't do it.

Comment: Ok good to know. And for reference, 'MVR' is Motor Vehicle Record (or Report)

Comment: Having been through the HireRight process a few months ago, I suggest you fill out everything fully and honestly.  If they ask about it, put it down because HireRight WILL check everything.   My start date for my current job was postponed for a week because I left one thing out of my history.  It wasn't serious and was cleared up fairly quickly, but its always better to be honest.   In some cases they'd rather you be honest about a black mark than try to cover it up.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it best to raise the matter to HR before they see the HireRight report?

No it's not, if they have a policy that would affect you, there is nothing that bringing it into the limelight will change.

Otherwise it's not related to your position and will probably make no difference. Best to let these things take care of themselves one way or the other rather than make a drama over it before it even becomes an issue. Time enough to address it when it actually needs to be dealt with.

Comment: Agreed, for this "*Otherwise it's not related to your position and will probably make no difference.*"  In other words, unless driving is a part of your job I don't see the need of you bringing it up.  It either will or will not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would bring it up with them - but only as a casual/FYI sort of thing. From the sounds of it you aren't required to drive for your role  so it shouldn't be something that affects your ability to do the role.

The advantages to bringing it up are:

1) It will save you worrying about it while you await the results of the background check - despite the fact that rationally it *shouldn't* make a difference it's the sort of niggling worry that can fester and stress you out. Clearly it is already doing so to a certain extent as you felt the need to post here.

2) It demonstrates to the company that you are an up-front and honest kind of person, it's not something you can quantify but these are attributes that employers generally value so it's a good way to demonstrate those qualities.

Comment: I had to downvote this answer. From the wording he's using, MVR (Motor Vehicle Record) (which I know that sounds weird, but in the US, an MVR also includes the driving history of the driver), it sounds like he's in the United States. So assuming he's in the United States, I don't think he should bring this up at all, even casually (unless it's brought up as part of a business trip and a car rental is the only option being offered by HR).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk it's ok, that's what the voting system is for :) Not sure I follow your reasoning though since he's indicated that they are already doing a check which includes looking at the MVR it's surely going to come up regardless. My thinking was along the lines of him having it come to light on *his* terms

Comment: A long time ago, I interned in the HR department of a large laboratory. Any irrelevant information that could be used to illegally discriminate against job applicants had to be blacked out by our receptionist/person receiving the mail. Now, I don't know how the background checks were handled. I never got to see those. But I would expect the same thing to have happened in those cases as well. If irrelevant negative information came in, especially if the hiring manager was not supposed to have it, I would assume it got blacked out by a dedicated person who was given that task.